# The favourite question icon conveys a wrong message?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, user-interface

I saw this question favorited four times and my intuitive response was that four people marked it as something bad. It's because of the "danger like" color of the star.

Here's my suggestion; **make the star golden**

[image]

I checked a couple of other stackexchange sites, their stars are just fine.

Comment: Yeah, why is it red in the first place? There's nothing else red [on the site](http://cdn.sstatic.net/uxmeta/img/sprites.png).

Comment: Perhaps the designer was Chinese, who thought it [symbolizes good fortune and joy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_in_Chinese_culture#Red)

Comment: I note that the "favourite" icon as used in ux.chat is a golden colour (just smaller)

Comment: If I favourite this question, the colour of the icon is significantly duller than that shown in the image; it's almost brown now.  I guess the site admins agreed with your critique and responded!

Comment: Nope, it's dull only on the meta site, as it was. On the main site it's bright red, as it was.

Answer (score 7):

It's not red until you have favourited yourself too. It only turns that colour after you favourite the question. It's very discoverable what the colour means in the context of the action you have just taken. I don't see any real justification for anyone being confused.

Comment: Yes, in the context of the action just taken, it's fine. But if I happen to browse the same question again sometime, it's not as intuitive. However, I agree, even though red, it's a star which generally means a good thing. **Can you tell why a golden star is not better?**

Answer (score 6):

I'd wager it would look too much like the golden badge icons.

Regardless of what you connect the color red to (which is personal, or at the most a cultural thing) it's a color that stands out from the rest of the color scheme.

Marking something as your "favorite" stresses its importance. Thus, standing out from the rest of the color-scheme is a good thing.

I'd say keep it.

Answer (score 0):

The icon used for the favorite looks to be the same as the badges. So, as Dirk v B suggests, making it gold would confuse a favorite question with a gold badge.

If the red color is an issue, a solution would be to not only change the color, but use something like the the positive space star in the normal StackOverflow site vice the negative space star we're using on UX. The star is a common scheme for favorites or recommendations in the wild, and modifying that would have the double benefit of making it look less like the badges.